# How to Get number of views in telegram channels with API

Tags: node.js, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I already use `telegram bot APIs` but it dosen't have any methods to get number of views.

Can I use telegram Client APIs for this?

Answer (score 0):

with telegram api you cant get post view numbers.

you can use madelineproto library( https://docs.madelineproto.xyz ) for this